# Continuity of the period of solutions of a second order ODE, with respect to their initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

There is a second order ODE
$$\ddot{x} + b(x) \dot{x}^2 + c(x) = 0$$
with continuous, and locally lipschitz coefficients b, c : $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Assume the ODE has 2 partial periodic solutions $x_1(t)$, and $x_2(t)$, s.t.
$x_1(0) = a$, $\dot{x}_1(0) = 0$, $x_2(0) = a + \epsilon$, $\dot{x}_2(0) = 0$.

It's intuitively clear that if $\epsilon$ is small, and if the solutions cover the same stationary points, their periods should be close. Speaking shorter, period continuously depends on $\epsilon$ in some interval.

**Question**: is there a theorem which proves this? Maybe there is a more general theorem for the second order equations in the form  $\ddot{x}=f(x,\dot{x})$.

**Solution**:
I tried to prove this by myself, but my solution looks too complicated.

Firstly, I show that 
$$\dot{x}^{2}\left(a,x\right)=-\int_{a}^{x}c\left(s\right)\cdot e^{-2\int_{s}^{x}b\left(w\right)dw}ds \text{.}$$
So, the period is 
$$T=2\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^{2}\left(x\right)}} \text{,}$$
where $b$ is a root of $$\dot{x}^2(a,b)=0 \text{.}$$
After that, I need to prove that the integral $T$ converges, and it continuesly depends on $a$ on some interval.

Comment: It seems that there is something else known about your kind of systems. How do you know that there is a continuum of periodic solutions?

Comment: By the way, if you really have a continuum of periodic solutions, the method is quite simple: you construct a cross-section through some point of your periodic trajectory and prove that the return time varies continuously on this cross-section. This kind of statement uses smooth dependence of flow on initial conditions and time + implicit function theorem. The proof for (maybe not exactly this, but quite similar) statement can be found in book by Leontovich, Andronov, Gordon and Mayer _Qualitative theory of second-order dynamic systems_ (_Качественная теория динамических систем на плоскости_)

Comment: @Evgeny this equation has some symmetry properties, like, time direction invariance, and phase portrait mirror-symetry. These means the system doesn't have limit cycles at all. if a periodic trajectory the system has is not limit cycle, it should be a continuum of periodic trajectories in the neighborhood.

Comment: I look through the book, I couldn't find something about period. The only interesting thing is the following: the square covering by trajectory is the locally lipschitz function of epsilon. Arnold wrote that the period equals $T=dS/dE$, where E is "energy", S is square. I am thinking about this...

Comment: I'm not sure that I remember this well, but wasn't this formula derived only for conservative case? By the way, in LAGM's book the proof is at pages 90-91 (_Функция последования_ ).

Comment: @Evgeny, this equation can be represented as lagrange system.

Comment: Well I think you are right, though I don't understand what do you mean by "Lagrange" system here. Speaking about symmetries, I can see that this system is reversible with respect to involution $(x, y) \mapsto (x, -y)$, so yeah, that explains why we have continuum of periodic solutions.